# How do i validate a Stylevision generated XSLT outside of Altova Stylevision?

Tags: xslt, altova, stylevision

How do i use XSLT generated files from Altova Stylevision outside of Altova products? They work fine within XML Spy and Stylevision, but not when i try to validate and run the files in e.g Visual Studio.

Comment: By default Altova generates XSLT that contains calls to Altova-specific extension functions and therefore requires Altova at run-time. I believe they might have an option to generate XSLT without such extensions, but I can't help you with the details.

Comment: Found out that VS uses xslt 1.0(I think). Tried a Saxon processor forn.net and it worked perfect!